# Can Firebase Be Used With A Swift Framework Project?

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

I took the following steps:

1. Create a brand new swift single view application.
2. Add a pod file that expresses a dependency on Firebase
3. Install the pods
4. Open the resultant workspace and build for simulator
5. The builds succeeds

I then repeated these steps except that in step 1 I created a brand new swift cocoa touch framework. Now the builds fails.

As you can see below, Firebase is referencing undefined symbols. And those symbols are mostly ones that I recognize and would expect to be present: UIScreen, UIWebView, UIView, etc.

I suspect that this all has something to do with the fact that Firebase is a static library (as is pointed out [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-talk/ewsVc_FN8N0/47aivpDNBQAJ) by Mike McDonald as a reason why Firebase cannot be used with Carthage).

I am at the limit of my understanding of the differences/consequences of applications, frameworks, and libraries. Can anyone help me to understand what is going on here?

---

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIScreen", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuthWebViewController_86c5ea5aedb4d33fd68b8660d74be54c.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIWebView", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuthWebView_25b1b3be4cd535a13078fd46686b4a67.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIActivityIndicatorView", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuthWebView_25b1b3be4cd535a13078fd46686b4a67.o)
>     "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_UIView", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FIRAuthWebView in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuthWebView_25b1b3be4cd535a13078fd46686b4a67.o)
>     "_CGRectZero", referenced from:
>         -[FIRAuthWebView createWebView] in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuthWebView_25b1b3be4cd535a13078fd46686b4a67.o)
>     "_UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey", referenced from:
>         -[FIRAuthAppDelegateProxy initWithApplication:] in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuthAppDelegateProxy_d84ca069394368ea9e8127dbd13cc324.o)
>     "_UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification", referenced from:
>         ___23-[FIRAuth initWithApp:]_block_invoke_2 in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuth_cce0d8e8cd5be2b376ebd7862de82f18.o)
>         -[FIRAuth dealloc] in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuth_cce0d8e8cd5be2b376ebd7862de82f18.o)
>         -[FIRClearcutLogger init] in FirebaseCoreDiagnostics(FIRClearcutLogger_d1e734d02d610ce1f3d8c66a4d80fa41.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIColor", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuthWebView_25b1b3be4cd535a13078fd46686b4a67.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIViewController", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in FirebaseAnalytics(UIViewController+FIRAScreenClassName_936040e31cd4dddd6f71a52ea1701d0d.o)
>         l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_UIViewController_$_FIRAScreenClassName in FirebaseAnalytics(UIViewController+FIRAScreenClassName_936040e31cd4dddd6f71a52ea1701d0d.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRAuthWebViewController in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuthWebViewController_86c5ea5aedb4d33fd68b8660d74be54c.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIPageViewController", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAScreenViewReporter_ac44c2e1b22c7193e316d64ecdc73845.o)
>     "_UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification", referenced from:
>         +[FIRAMeasurement load] in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAMeasurement_41f8c6ad6e1fd9e66100bee4ee2fdd35.o)
>     "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_UIViewController", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FIRAuthWebViewController in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuthWebViewController_86c5ea5aedb4d33fd68b8660d74be54c.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIView", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRAuthWebView in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuthWebView_25b1b3be4cd535a13078fd46686b4a67.o)
>     "_UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey", referenced from:
>         +[FIRAMeasurement handleAppDidFinishLaunching:] in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAMeasurement_41f8c6ad6e1fd9e66100bee4ee2fdd35.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UINavigationController", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAScreenViewReporter_ac44c2e1b22c7193e316d64ecdc73845.o)
>         objc-class-ref in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuthURLPresenter_f9c1670c7b472e1f12d82d1c6f46940a.o)
>         objc-class-ref in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuthDefaultUIDelegate_57cb718a1d423e27d0d50a3bf9524d86.o)
>     "_UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification", referenced from:
>         ___48-[FIRAMeasurement startMeasurementOnWorkerQueue]_block_invoke in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAMeasurement_41f8c6ad6e1fd9e66100bee4ee2fdd35.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UITabBarController", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAScreenViewReporter_ac44c2e1b22c7193e316d64ecdc73845.o)
>         objc-class-ref in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuthDefaultUIDelegate_57cb718a1d423e27d0d50a3bf9524d86.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIBarButtonItem", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuthWebViewController_86c5ea5aedb4d33fd68b8660d74be54c.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIDevice", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAEnvironmentInfo_0da493a96efd1159c2c84454cf5a7f9d.o)
>         objc-class-ref in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAMeasurement_41f8c6ad6e1fd9e66100bee4ee2fdd35.o)
>         objc-class-ref in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAInAppPurchaseTransactionReporter_51b6624ff1330bf43a3ed7d9ba76e1ba.o)
>         objc-class-ref in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAAEU_58e35a32128cb3aedeb97de41a9b356d.o)
>         objc-class-ref in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAIdentity_8e9287d1fd6072066ad3b1332bc62373.o)
>         objc-class-ref in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuthKeychain_ee296104c7d22b9c7b07f84e7067440c.o)
>         objc-class-ref in FirebaseCore(FIRAppEnvironmentUtil_d91f40fc45222373d7f99c8b2ea3c83a.o)
>         ...
>     "_UIWindowDidResignKeyNotification", referenced from:
>         -[FIRAScreenViewReporter init] in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAScreenViewReporter_ac44c2e1b22c7193e316d64ecdc73845.o)
>     "_UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification", referenced from:
>         ___48-[FIRAMeasurement startMeasurementOnWorkerQueue]_block_invoke in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAMeasurement_41f8c6ad6e1fd9e66100bee4ee2fdd35.o)
>         -[FIRAScreenViewReporter init] in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAScreenViewReporter_ac44c2e1b22c7193e316d64ecdc73845.o)
>         ___23-[FIRAuth initWithApp:]_block_invoke_2 in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuth_cce0d8e8cd5be2b376ebd7862de82f18.o)
>         -[FIRAuth dealloc] in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuth_cce0d8e8cd5be2b376ebd7862de82f18.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIWindow", referenced from:
>         l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_UIWindow_$_FIRAScreenClassName in FirebaseAnalytics(UIWindow+FIRAScreenClassName_93645224f692c290f5d755885ec7f4c8.o)
>     "_UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification", referenced from:
>         ___48-[FIRAMeasurement startMeasurementOnWorkerQueue]_block_invoke in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAMeasurement_41f8c6ad6e1fd9e66100bee4ee2fdd35.o)
>         -[FIRAScreenViewReporter init] in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAScreenViewReporter_ac44c2e1b22c7193e316d64ecdc73845.o)
>     "_UIBackgroundTaskInvalid", referenced from:
>         -[FIRAMeasurement initWithDatabaseName:persistedConfig:network:scheduler:alarm:options:] in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAMeasurement_41f8c6ad6e1fd9e66100bee4ee2fdd35.o)
>         -[FIRAMeasurement swapBackgroundTaskWithNewTaskID:] in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAMeasurement_41f8c6ad6e1fd9e66100bee4ee2fdd35.o)
>         -[FIRAMeasurement terminateBackgroundTask] in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAMeasurement_41f8c6ad6e1fd9e66100bee4ee2fdd35.o)
>         -[FIRClearcutLogger init] in FirebaseCoreDiagnostics(FIRClearcutLogger_d1e734d02d610ce1f3d8c66a4d80fa41.o)
>         -[FIRClearcutLogger dealloc] in FirebaseCoreDiagnostics(FIRClearcutLogger_d1e734d02d610ce1f3d8c66a4d80fa41.o)
>         -[FIRClearcutLogger sendLogsWithCompletionHandler:] in FirebaseCoreDiagnostics(FIRClearcutLogger_d1e734d02d610ce1f3d8c66a4d80fa41.o)
>         ___51-[FIRClearcutLogger sendLogsWithCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke in FirebaseCoreDiagnostics(FIRClearcutLogger_d1e734d02d610ce1f3d8c66a4d80fa41.o)
>         ...
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIApplication", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAAppDelegateProxy_2421946053f1c5c031a7dceeaf4d9408.o)
>         objc-class-ref in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuth_cce0d8e8cd5be2b376ebd7862de82f18.o)
>         objc-class-ref in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuthAppDelegateProxy_d84ca069394368ea9e8127dbd13cc324.o)
>         objc-class-ref in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuthDefaultUIDelegate_57cb718a1d423e27d0d50a3bf9524d86.o)
>         objc-class-ref in FirebaseCoreDiagnostics(FIRClearcutLogger_d1e734d02d610ce1f3d8c66a4d80fa41.o)
>         objc-class-ref in FirebaseInstanceID(FIRMessagingLog_045f628692bcbe68f0c668c89b92b24f.o)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Comment: I haven't tested swift cocoa touch framework, but with the CocoaPods 1.4.0 static_frameworks feature, Firebase (and other static library) CocoaPods can be dependencies of other CocoaPods.  Details at https://github.com/paulb777/blog.cocoapods.org/blob/f7323d72ed1ddb653ac1e74ddf77c681a6633a85/_posts/Static-Framework.markdown

Comment: Paul, thank you for this. In the link that you provided I read: "Because dynamic libraries cannot depend upon static libraries ...". So, that seems

Comment: to be that.

I would love to give it a try. Would you please advise me? 1) Should I go ahead and install 1.4.0? 2) Can I still keep 1.2.0 just in case? 3) What should I do in Xcode - create a static library project and then install the Firebase pods into it?

Comment: There are stackoverflow answer's that describe how to work with different CocoaPods versions. Only create your app in Xcode. Create your static library framework that depends on Firebase as a CocoaPod. As an example, see how the various Firebase pods depend on each other at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/Example/Podfile and in the podspec's in the same repo.

Comment: @Verticon Did you get any solution for this ?

Comment: @Dhruv No, I have continued to add Firebase to my application directly instead of to my Framework. When I get more time I am going to explore Paul Beusterien's suggestions

Comment: @Dhruv  : Anything new on this?