# Using firebase framework within cocoa touch framework

Tags: swift, firebase, cocoa-touch

I’m developing a framework where I need to use firebase internally.

I added firebase framework manually to my framework as cocoapods didn’t work.

Now, I’m able to build my framework and use it on my local system as expected. But it creates problem when I ship it to other devs and it fails with following errors.

[image]

I tried several ways like adding firebase.h in framework's header file. But none of the approaches are working.

Also, apart from this approach, I tried manually adding firebase to main app, where it gave the logs saying duplicate frameworks found.

What am I doing wrong in adding firebase to framework ?

I've already checked some of the related question such as [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47729940/can-firebase-be-used-with-a-swift-framework-project) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47544216/crash-when-use-firebase-analytics-in-a-project-sdk-cocoa-touch-framework)

Comment: Can you clarify *cocoapods didn’t work*? I've used cocoapods successfully many times. Is that it didn't work because of an error or didn't work because of your use case? The CocoaPods.app also works very well and allows Firebase to be added to projects with no command line interaction.

Comment: @Jay my context on didn't work was with respect to using of firebase via cocoapods in my cocoatouch framework. It gave me same error with cocoapods as well.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect, that after transferring the code into the other machine, owner does not runs

`pod install`

terminal command, so physically the framework does not exist.

Comment: I've mentioned that using cocoa pods didn't work in building my framework, so I've manually added firebase frameworks in my cocoa touch framework.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm Aaron answer: be sure to specify a complete, correct path.
I usually avoid as the "evil" cocoaPods (getting worse and worse to use..)
so I downloaded the zip and added all the folder. 
I specify ONLY "Framework search path" and "Header search path".

Library search path is empty.

note: as suggested by documentation, I added FireBase.h AND module.modulemap, TOO. (and set -objC flag, too)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding one or more search paths for the framework and header file will resolve the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First de integrate pod after try with fresh.

```
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
```

Answer (score 0):

CocoaPods 1.5.0 static library feature does not work with FirebaseAnalytics because of the non-modular headers in FirebaseAnalytics.h.

Reported at [CocoaPods/CocoaPods#7542](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7542).

Workaround is a similar post_install step similar to [this](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/Example/Podfile#L217).

Because the fix is a breaking change, it is targeted for the next Firebase major release.

Comment: FYI, I haven't used cocoapods for some reasons. Now does this workaround really work ?